# QFileDialog choose file or folder

Tags: dialog, qt5, qfiledialog

Is there a way to choose file or a folder in QFileDialog window. As far as I've reviewed the documentation and it turns out that I can either open file or directory but I can't use the dialog to open both types at the same time. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QFileDialog that accepts a single file or a single directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520304/qfiledialog-that-accepts-a-single-file-or-a-single-directory)